# How to use Puppeteer Sharp to click on specific element of a web page

Tags: c#, puppeteer-sharp

I need to extract some data from this web page: https://www.sportsbetting.ag/live-betting
I am using PuppeteerSharp (version 2.0.4) in Visual Studio 2019 for a C# project on Windows 10.
I want to click on “Calendar” Tab, but I can’t finish my job, and I can’t find useful help.
I guess at this web page uses Frames, when I use Puppeteer Recorder or Headerless recorder, the results are rather useless.
I also tried to see from the Chrome developer tools to see the network requests, I can see the HTTP POST at: https://dgslivebetting.sportsbetting.ag/ngwbet.aspx/calFrameHtml
With some headers, but I tried using Advanced REST Client version 15.0.7 to make a HTTP Post request, but I got 403 response.

Access denied | dgslivebetting.sportsbetting.ag used Cloudflare to restrict access
Using web browser with hand click on the “Calendar” Tab always works.
But I have to use PuppeteerSharp to automatically grab some information from the web site.
Please advice on how to do this via PuppeteerSharp.
See the picture to understand my meaning.  I can't see the picture uploaded!

[image: click on the Calendar tab to see data]

Comment: Could you use Selenium instead?

Comment: I tried Selenium before, but it looks rather bad. So I lost interest.  If you have any idea on how to click this by PuppeteerSharp or PlaywrightSharp, please let me know.